# how can i handle webhooks inside a npx vite app?

Tags: node.js, express, dynamic, three.js, webhooks

i created a three.js app using [this tutorial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation). Now i want the displayed data to be dynamic - so i decided to use webhooks. So i found [this example](https://reintech.io/blog/how-to-use-node-js-to-create-a-webhook-receiver) creating a webhook receiver.

But how do i combine these two approaches? When creating an webserver like the last one, how is it possible to update the content of a previous GET request?

About lighter approaches or a solution to my problem I am very happy - Thanks!